# why while loop do not need user to input in c++

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ and reading c++ primer plus, but I don't understand why this code need two "cin >> ch". I know the first cin will read character that was user input.but then I delete first "cin >> ch" and run code ,the program have no error.So the fist cin is necessary? why the second cin needn't user to input?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    char ch;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Enter characters; enter # to quit:\n";
    cin >> ch; //get a character
    while (ch != '#')
    {
        cout << ch;
        ++count;
        cin >> ch; // get the next character
    }
    cout << endl << count << " characters read\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try and think about what `ch != #` means if the first `cin` does not exist. Also, what is the result of that  `cout<<ch;` when you run that code?

Comment: Without the first `cin`, what would be the value of `ch` when you first enter the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate your input right inside condition of `while` loop.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int count = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter characters; enter # to quit:\n";

    while (std::cin >> ch && ch != '#')
    {
        std::cout << "entered: " << ch << std::endl;
        ++count;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << count << " characters read" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When `while` condition is entered it will wait for you to enter anything first. Once input is received it will check if the input is not #. If input is not #  the loop is entered, input printed out, counter increased, and back to waiting for another input. If # is entered, condition becomes false, and loop is aborted.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the first `cin` then count will never be incremented. The user can enter `#` character before entering the loop and the program can never enter it therefore.

Comment: It's much worse than that. If they remove the first `cin`, then `ch` has an undefined value, and the program has undefined behaviour, so there's no point trying to reason about what it does.

Answer (score -1):

The first cin>>ch is obviously used to take input from user but you
have again accepting data in while loop using the same variable name "ch" ,
So when you run the program it will not give u error but accept only first value that you have accept before the while loop not in while loop.
  In while loop you can assign new value to variable "ch" but not accept the new value again.